# Как сократить данный участок кода?

Tags: java

Как сократить или сделать более читаемым данный участок кода?

```
if (string.equals("Buy")) {
    Main.playerOne.buy();
} else if (string.equals("Open")) {
    Main.playerOne.openBox();
} else if (string.equals("Info")) {
    Main.printStats();
} else if (string.equals("Inventory")) {
    Main.playerOne.inventory.printInventory();
} else if (string.equals("Clean Inventory")) {
    Main.playerOne.inventory.cleanInventory();
} else if (string.equals("Tax")) {
    Main.playerOne.inventory.taxItem();
} else if (string.equals("Help")) {

} else {
    System.out.println("\nДанная команда не найдена!");
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html ?

Comment: Вы смотрели на мой код ? И как по вашему я запихну это в switch ?

Comment: а если ява старая :), сделайте массив, ищите в нем строку и используйте индекс в свитче. может, это более читаемо :)

Comment: @splash58, только не массив, а HashMap. И, учитывая, что жизненный цикл даже Java 7 подошел к концу, более старую версию новичку мучить бессмысленно.

Comment: @Nofate я еще питон не начал читать, до явы с андроидом чуть позже надо будет добраться :)  у меня пока квартальник пчп тока кончается через месяц :)))

Comment: @TwerTrue а в чем проблема запихнуть ваш код в switch?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда есть много условий для конструкции `if-else`, берут специальную конструкцию `switch`. Ваш код с этой конструкцией:

```
switch (string) {
    case "Buy":
        Main.playerOne.buy();
        break;
    case "Open":
         Main.playerOne.openBox();
        break;
    case "Info":
        Main.printStats();
        break;
    case "Inventory":
        Main.playerOne.inventory.printInventory();
        break;
    case "Clean Inventory":
        Main.playerOne.inventory.cleanInventory();
        break;
    case "Tax":
        Main.playerOne.inventory.taxItem();
        break;
    case "Help":
        // команда
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("\nДанная команда не найдена!");

    }
```

Аргументом к `switch()` записывается переменная. Есть набор кейсов, содержащих возможные значения это переменной. Чтобы ограничить тело кейса используется ключевое слово `break`. Если его нет, команды будут выполнять, пока не встретят `break`  или не закончится тело `switch`. Если подходящего кейса нет, будет выполнена команда из блока `default`.

Comment: Только надо сделать ремарку, что `switch` со `String` работает только с 7-й версией Java

Comment: Я знаю конструкцию switch case но не когда не работал со строками в ней

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения виртуальной машины Java - не такое уж плохое решение.
С точки зрения надёжности и принятых в Java конвенций - тут есть над чем поработать. К сожалению, вы не представили весь код файла, а только его часть.

Основной недостаток - организация прямого доступа к полям класса:

```
Main.playerOne.inventory
```

Для обеспечения надёжности нужно сделать как-то так:

```
PlayerOne playerOne = Main.getPlayerOne();
if (null !=playerOne) {
    playerOne.getInventory()
    //...
}
```

С точки зрения надёжных проверок на равенство строковых данных нужно переписать Ваш код так:

```
if ("Buy".equals(string)) {
    Main.playerOne.buy();
} else if ("Open".equals(string)) {
    Main.playerOne.openBox();
} 
//...
```

Надеюсь, идея ясна.

Comment: Читаемости это всё определённо не улучшит)

Comment: @andreymal, это не для читаемости. Если в переменной null, то вызов null.equals грохнется, а если поменять местами константу и переменную, то сравнение просто даст false.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @Qwertiy я это всё прекрасно понимаю, но изначально вопрос таки про читаемость)

Comment: @andreymal, про повышение читаемости я ответил. К сожелению, не знаю, как записать нужный код на джаве.

Comment: Да и ещё можно узнать как можно избежать вот этого ? Main.playerOne.inventory.cleanInventory(); в данном случали Main это класс, playerOne это статический объект на основе класса Player, inventory это объект на основе класса Inventory, а cleanInventory() это уже метод inventory, так как можно упростить эту запись так как меня это иногда путает

Comment: @TwerTrue, освойте принципы SOLID (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), старайтесь их придерживаться, и проектировать в парадигме ООП станет легче.

Answer (score 3):

Сложить функции в словарь с ключом-строкой. Словарь этот вынести в какое-нибудь статическое поле.

В методе доставать функцию из словаря по ключу и если она там была, вызывать.

Могу привести пример кода на C#. Знаю, что в последней джаве подобное тоже врзможно при помощи функциональных интерфейсов и приведения функций к ним. В более ранней можно было бы использовать более громоздкий вариант с инлайновой имплементацией интерфейса, хотя такой вариант мне не нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с 1.7 в Java можно использовать строковые данные в операторе switch:

[ссылка](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Приводите код классов полностью.
2. Изучите подходы к ООП. В чем конкретно ваши минусы с точки зрения ООП?
   У вас существуют вложенные классы, судя по их названию и их методов, вы пишите игру.
   Грамотно инкапсулируйте. Метод Main это то, откуда ваша программа будет стартовать, если же вам метод Main нужен для тестов вашей модели игры/персонажей, то используйте классы с отдельными методами тестирования. (Junit можно за час разобраться)
   Хорошая практика использования get/set (геттеров и сеттеров). Поля должны быть private, т.е. закрыты к прямому обращению через оператор доступа "."

**НЕ**

Class {
Inventory inventory;
}

**А**

Class {
Inventory inventory;
getInventory(){
return invetory;
}

3. Изучите принципы SOLID. Само прочтение названий принцип ничего не даст. ДЛя вас книга Head First по Паттернам проектирования сейчас самое то.
   Но для вашего уровня также необходимо подтянуть знания возможностей самой Java. Раз вы не понимаете как применить Switch().
   книга Head First Изучаем Java для вас думаю тоже подойдет.

НУ и ответ на ваш вопрос код, кстати, согласующийся с принципом "открытости для расширения и закрытости для изменения"

```
public class EventManager {
    EventManager(){
        gameEvents.put("buy",new BuyHandler());
        gameEvents.put("openbox", new OpenBoxHandler());
    }
    
    private Map<String ,GameEventHandler> gameEvents = new HashMap();
    
    public void addEventHandler(String nameEvent, GameEventHandler handler){
        gameEvents.put(nameEvent,handler);
    }
    public void handleEvent(String eventName){
        GameEventHandler handler = gameEvents.get(eventName);
        handler.doSomething();
    }
    

}
```

> public interface GameEventHandler {    T doSomething();
>
> }

реализация

> public class BuyHandler implements GameEventHandler {     public Object
> doSomething() {       return null;    } }

Comment: также как написано выше возможно иницизалиация в блоках static и non-static.
Советую посмотреть готовые игровые паттерны проектирования