# Для чего нужен блок static?

Tags: java

Где в реальной жизни может использоваться такой блок в программировании? Зачем тогда конструктор? Да я понимаю, что конструктор будет вызываться при каждом новом создании экземпляра класса, а статик блок единожды. Но в какой момент пройдет инициализация статик блока и где реально он применяется?

Comment: Спасибо ребята за ответы. немного ситуация прояснилась. Но как я понял проблема в том что, есть этапы инициализации о которых я не знаю. То есть сначала инициализируется сам класс,а потом уже при создание его инстанса врубается конструктор это класса? Я правильно понял? Есть ли инфа где почитать можно про эти этапы?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Статические блоки вызываются в момент инициализации класса (когда ClassLoader будет грузить его в MetaSpace, [подробнее в JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)), и могут использоваться для иницализации статических переменных. Зачем вызывать каждый раз инициализацию статических переменных в конструкторе, если можно сделать это единожды, таким образом не тратить ресурсы на повторные инициализации?

Answer (score 10):

Мне кажется у вас небольшое недопонимание разницы между `static` и `instance` полями класса.

Поля с модификатором `static` могут быть использованы даже если не было создано не одного экземпляра класса (ни одного объекта) - и они являются общими для всех экземпляров класса.

`static` методы соответственно могут взаимодействовать только со `static` полями.

В конструкторе вы можете задавать значения переменным инстанса(объекта). Под каждый инстанс выделяется отдельная память в которой и хранятся переменные инстанса, и они свои для каждого инстанса.

Кроме `static` блока инициализации если еще не статик блок инициализации - он выполняется **до** конструктора, например:

```
public class Test {

    static {
        System.out.println("Static");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Non-static block");
    }

    public Test() {
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Интересно, я только вчера использовал `static` блок. Я его использую не часто, но вот упрощенный пример от моего кода его использования:

```
public class MovieData {
    public static List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>(),
        directors = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
      add("Jurassic Park", "Steven Spielberg");
      add("The Dark Night", "Christopher Nolan");
      add("Titanic", "James Cameron");
    }

    private static void add(String title, String director) {
      titles.add(title);
      directors.add(director);
    }
}
```

Как @zzashpaupat отметил в его ответе, блоки `static` вызываются при инициализации класса.

Answer (score 8):

static блок выполняется при первом обращении к классу. 
А нужен он для инициализации статических полей, например:

```
class Cls {
    static OtherCls someField;
    static String[] list = new String[3];

    static {
        someField = new OtherCls();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i] = Integer.toString(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом, OtherCls будет интанц-ан, а массив будет заполнен перед самым первым обращением к классу Cls

Answer (score 2):

Этот блок - блок, который выполнится единожды при инициализации класса (именно класса, а не инстанса). Собственно, для этого и нужен.

Вот недавно [отвечая на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433847/178988) посоветовал сохранить набор методов в словаре. Это можно было бы сделать в статическом блоке, чтобы иметь единожды созданный заполненный словарь. Кстати, в C# это можно было бы сделать ещё и через инициализатор коллекции, но в джаве такого вроде нет.