# Что делает static блок кода java?

Tags: java, sql

Что за блок static? Это анонимный метод или что? Как и когда он выполняется? И можно кратенько что тут происходит?

```
public class UserDAO {

private  static Connection connection;

static {
    String url = null;
    String username = null;
    String password = null;


    try (InputStream in = UserDAO.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("persistence.properties")) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        url = properties.getProperty("url");
        username = properties.getProperty("username");
        password = properties.getProperty("password");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: почитайте сначала про объекты, потом про инициализацию, потом про статическую инициализацию, потом овердофига по джаве, а потом уже про jdbc

Comment: Обратите внимание на [ответ @Constantine](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434023) он напрямую отвечает на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта конструкция называется **блок статической инициализации,** он выполняется 1 раз при загрузке класса класс лоадером.

Конкретно в Вашем примере блок статической инициализации создает соединение и сохраняет ссылку на него в статическое же поле.

В целом статика порождает проблемы. т.к. ее переиниализация часто не тривиальна, если не невозможна.

Если в момент загрузки программы соединение по какой либо причине не будет создано, придется каким то еще другим способом вызывать повторно процедуру соединения, так как блок статической инициализации второй раз выполнить без черной магии нельзя.

Классы использующие статику и статическую интциализацию сложнее, а в некоторых случаях невозможно качественно покрыть unit тестами. т.к. у кода, который выполняет тестирование нет контроля над статическим полем, тем более если оно огорожено `private`, а еще хуже `private final`, или нет возможности **не выполнять** блок статической инициализации

—-

Это дело лучше например заменить на отдельный класс, это будет его зона ответственности, а DAOшки в свою очередь получают ссылку на него при конструировании. В каком нибудь спринге это было бы поле с аннотацией `@Autowired` , которое инициализируется `DI` контейнером, ну или на худой конец как аргумент конструктора или сеттер.

Это может покпзаться не так изящно но увы, некоторые инструменты опасны или таят скрытые проблемы, статика именно такой инструмент

Comment: вопрос замисовали т.к. это есть в любой книге по java